# Как получить все строки по ID MySql в ассоциативный массив

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Есть вот такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно получить все записи с chat_id равным какому-то числу, к примеру 1.

Нужно, чтобы массив был по типу такого:

```js
let messages = [
 "0" : [
   "messId" : '1',
   "sender" : '0',
   "message": 'dfdashfhsdf'
   //.......
 ],
 "1" : [
   "messId" : '1',
   "sender" : '0',
   "message": 'dfdashfhsdf'
   //.......
 ],
 //.......
]
```

Попробовал сделать так

```html
<?php
$messages = $conn - > query("SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(messID),JSON_ARRAYAGG(chat_id),JSON_ARRAYAGG(sender),JSON_ARRAYAGG(message),JSON_ARRAYAGG(date) AS message FROM chats_messages WHERE chat_id = 6");
$messages = $messages - > fetch_assoc();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). В данном случае - вложенный.

Comment: можете ли написать пример конкретно с моими данными? Не совсем пойму как ей пользоваться)

Comment: Можете написать пример?

Comment: Пример могу. Но создавать под это структуру и набивать её данными... сделайте fiddle на 5-7 записей (желательно взять пару реальных диалогов, заменив message), и покажите точный ответ именно для этих данных.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hatf8kzp/

Comment: вот ссылка, там желаемый результат. А как сделать в fiddle записи из БД не знаю)

Comment: У меня что-то получается, но результат совсем не такой как хочется

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, у Вас данные лежат в таблице на сервере MySQL. Вы хотите запросом получить показанный JSON. Верно? А если верно - то fiddle должен быть с таблицей и данными в ней, чтобы на нём откатать запрос, который получит требуемый вывод.. А финальный JSON можно и тут форматированным текстом показать...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT messId, chat_id, sender, message
FROM table_name
WHERE chat_id=1 ;
```

Вот так. [И вот линк в помощь](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: Ну я еще не совсем дурак, и я сам это написать могу, проблема в том, как эти данные запаковать в массив двумерный.